detection of mouse hovering using pdcurses
I am making an implemintation of conway's game of life using c and wanted to make the game highlight the cell the mouse in hovering over but i can't seem to be able to catch mouse movements even though i used ALL_MOUSE_EVENTS and MOUSE_MOVED flags
here is the input handling code :
void handle_mouse_input(){
    MEVENT event;

    if(nc_getmouse(&event) != OK) return ;
    
    if(event.x >= Play_Start_X && event.x <= Play_End_X && event.y == Play_Y){

        Pause = !Pause;

    }else if(event.x >= Exit_Start_X && event.x <= Exit_End_X && event.y == Exit_Y){
        quit();
    }else if(event.x >= State_Start_X && event.y >= State_Start_Y && event.x <= State_End_X && event.y <= State_End_Y){
        lock_state();

        cell_state new_state = alive;
        unsigned x = ((event.x - State_Start_X) / 2) + X_Indent , y = event.y - State_Start_Y + Y_Indent;
        if(lookup_cell_state(Board , x , y , false) == alive){
            new_state = dead;
        }

        set_cell(Board , x , y , new_state);

        unlock_state();
    }else if(event.x >= Reset_Start_X && event.x <= Reset_End_X && event.y == Reset_Y){
        reset_board(Board);
    }
}

//the purpose of making the function of this type is to be used with pthreads
void *handle_input(void *arg){
    if(stdscr == NULL) pthread_exit(NULL);

    keypad(stdscr , true);
    mousemask(ALL_MOUSE_EVENTS | REPORT_MOUSE_POSITION , NULL);
    mouseinterval(0);
    noecho();
    int ch = 0;

    while(1){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&IO_Mutex);

        ch = getch();

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&IO_Mutex);

        if(ch == ERR){
            continue;
        }

        if(ch == KEY_MOUSE){
            handle_mouse_input();
        }else{
            handle_keyboard_input(ch);
        }

        flushinp();
    };

    return NULL;
}

I am running this on windows terminal
note : i am testing if i catch the mouse movement using a debugger thats why i didn't write an if statement to check for bstate yet

i found a solution(kind of)
here is the new code:
void handle_mouse_input(int ch){
    MEVENT event;
    static int Last_X = -1 , Last_Y = -1;

    if(getmouse(&event) != OK) return ;

    if(event.x != Last_X || event.y != Last_Y){
        unhighlight_exit_button();
        unhighlight_play_pause_button();
        unhighlight_reset_button();
        unhighlight_cells();

        if(event.x >= Play_Start_X && event.x <= Play_End_X && event.y == Play_Y){
            highlight_play_pause_button();
        }else if(event.x >= Exit_Start_X && event.x <= Exit_End_X && event.y == Exit_Y){
            highlight_exit_button();
        }else if(event.x >= State_Start_X && event.y >= State_Start_Y && event.x <= State_End_X && event.y <= State_End_Y ){
            unsigned x = (event.x - State_Start_X) / 2 , y = event.y - State_Start_Y;
            highlight_cell(x , y);

            render_state(Board , stdscr , State_Start_X , State_Start_Y , State_End_X , State_End_Y);
            refresh();
        }else if(event.x >= Reset_Start_X && event.x <= Reset_End_X && event.y == Reset_Y){
            highlight_reset_button();
        }
    }

    Last_X = event.x;
    Last_Y = event.y;

    if(ch != KEY_MOUSE) return ;

    if(event.x >= Play_Start_X && event.x <= Play_End_X && event.y == Play_Y){
        Pause = !Pause;
    }else if(event.x >= Exit_Start_X && event.x <= Exit_End_X && event.y == Exit_Y){
        quit();
    }else if(event.x >= State_Start_X && event.y >= State_Start_Y && event.x <= State_End_X && event.y <= State_End_Y ){
        lock_state();
        cell_state new_state = alive;
        unsigned x = ((event.x - State_Start_X) / 2) + X_Indent , y = event.y - State_Start_Y + Y_Indent;
        if(lookup_cell_state(Board , x , y , false) == alive){
            new_state = dead;
        }
        set_cell(Board , x , y , new_state);
        unlock_state();

        render_state(Board , stdscr , State_Start_X , State_Start_Y , State_End_X , State_End_Y);
        refresh();
    }else if(event.x >= Reset_Start_X && event.x <= Reset_End_X && event.y == Reset_Y){
        reset_board(Board);
    }
}

//the purpose of making the function of this type is to be used with pthreads
void *handle_input(void *arg){
    if(stdscr == NULL) return NULL;

    int ch = 0;

    ch = getch();

    handle_mouse_input(ch);
    
    if(ch == ERR){
        return NULL;
    }

    if(ch != KEY_MOUSE){
        handle_keyboard_input(ch);
    }

    flushinp();

    return NULL;
}

even though the windows terminal won't report movement , the position of the mouse is always updated even if no new event happens , so i handle the mouse input even if a mouse event didn't happen get the mouse event check its position to know which cell or button it is hovering over then check if a mouse event has happened
you can also implement a function that detects mouse movement by getting the new mouse position then comparing it to older the position
eg:

bool mouse_moved(int *new_x , int *new_y){
    static int x = -1 , y = -1;
    
    if(new_x == NULL || new_y == NULL) return false;

    MEVENT event;
    nc_getmouse(&event);

    *new_x = -1;
    *new_y = -1;
    if(event.x != x || event.y != y){
        *new_x = x = event.x;
        *new_y = y = event.y;

        return true;
    }

    return false
}


EDIT : turns out this only works with pdcurses

Windows terminal falls short of implementing ConsoleAPI (which is what PDCurses uses).  This is one of the defects in Windows terminal, as noted in the ncurses terminal database:
# Windows 10 22H2 (also Windows 11)
# Version 1.16.10261.0
#
# - Windows Terminal #1553: "Feature Request:  Mouse/Touch/Pointer Bindings
#   (like middle-click paste, right-click context menu, etc.)", compare to
#   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/mouse-event-record-str
#   This appears to be related to a problem with its implementation of the
#   Console API; the mouse does not work in a "Command Window" (e.g., as used
#   in the ncurses MinGW driver), although escape sequences work.

Reading issue #1553, it seems that the Windows terminal developers were more interested in redesigning the feature than making it work as it was implemented in ConsoleAPI.  Quoting from its Abstract:

We've had numerous requests to configure how the mouse behaves in the Terminal.
The original behavior was a simple duplication of how conhost behaved: a right
click will copy the a selection if there is one, or paste the clipboard if there
isn't. Over time, we've accumulated a number of scenarios that we believe can
all be addressed by allowing more fine-grained mouse binding support. However,
upon further review, ultimately, we don't really need deep mouse binding
support.

